# Rendering boolean Object in Cycles (problem!!) blender 3.6

Tags: cycles-render-engine, edges, geometry, boolean-modifier

I modeled a building using boolean, but when i render it, it shows many problems.
I tried gpu, cpu, experimental version of cycles, but it seems nothing works.
I uploaded the file, thanks for your time.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: it seems to work fine for me, are you using 3.5?

Comment: @moonboots what version do u use ? i'm using 3.6

Comment: I'm using 3.5, see what it gives: https://zupimages.net/up/23/16/xklc.png

Comment: @moonboots thank u, I'm gonna use 3.5 .

Comment: Blender 3.6 only moved to [BCON2 today](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/milestone/5) and isn't due for general release until the end of June so if you think that you've found a bug you should report it via the Help > Report a Bug menu in Blender.

Comment: @JohnEason done. thank u